# How to pass a prop with a default value in case the prop is empty without using the prop's "default" property

Tags: vue.js, ternary, prop

I'm using a [third party multi-language package](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#html) where translation values can only be obtained/used from component's template, not from component's logic (at least I can't find how to the latter).

I need to pass such translation value in some component as a default prop value:

```
:placeholder="{ propValue ? propValue : $t('value') }
```

If placeholder is explicitly specified then use that. If not, use $t('value') instead. What's the right way to write this?

I tried this in reaction to @Michael's answer:

```
import i18n from "@/utilities/i18n";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: i18n.t('register.agreeTermsCaptionLink')
    };
  }
};
```

Getting this error:

> _utilities_i18n__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.default.t is not a function

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can set default value to prop like this:

```
props: {
     propValue: {
         type: String,
         default: this.$t('value')
     }
}
```

With that in your template you need just to assign that value like: `:placeholder="propValue"`

Is that what you trying to achive?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error though: `TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined`

Comment: Did you register `$t` in your app or main file?

Comment: The `default` can't reference `this.$t` as `this` won't be the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Just remove brackets from prop expression: `:placeholder="propValue ? propValue : $t('value')"`

### Sotution 2

More complicated but helps to keep templates cleaner...

> where translation values can only be obtained/used from component's template, not from component's logic

With [vue-i18n](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) you can of course obtain translation directly in code by using `$t` function injected into your component instance like this: `this.$t('key.to.translation')`

Only problem is, this is not possible to use to initialize props default values because `this` is just not available there.

But `$t` in fact just returns instance function of `VueI18n` global object. So if you setup your VueI18n like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const messages = {
  en: {
    messages: {
      placeholder: "Placeholder"
    }
  },
  cz: {
    messages: {
      placeholder: "Zástupný symbol :)"
    }
  }
};

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: "en",
  messages
});
```

You can do this to provide translation as default value of your prop:

```js
import i18n from "../i18n";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      // default: this.$t("value") - Wont work as `this` is not Vue instance
      default: i18n.t("messages.placeholder")
    }
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-i18n-demo-0b95k)

Comment: Thanks! I don't get it, I do the same thing and I an error. See my edited question

Comment: It's important how your `@/utilities/i18n` file looks like. Is it really same as mine example ? `export  default` part is important...you need to export your `VueI18n` object...